# Conditional BULK INSERT for CSV files with different number of columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert, bcp

I've generated a BCP FORMAT FILE (xml) for importing a CSV file into a SQL SERVER table.  There are 100+ CSV files (representing IIS web logs).  Some sites collect 5 columns of data, and some sites collect 6 columns of data.  The first five columns are the same.

**Is there anyway I can check first how many columns the CSV file has BEFORE I do the BULK INSERT command?**  That way, I can choose the correct format file to use with the command without getting an error stating columns are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do this would be to open the file with something else (Powershell script, VBS, C#/VB.net, etc.) and check the first line, passing back a result to indicate how many columns it found.  There is nothing in SQL Server that will do this for you (short of loading the whole file as a single-column table).

Comment: Yep, ended up having to massage each file first (to set the TERMINATORS for each of the columns) so I was able to count the columns at that time.  Thanks!